# Get day old filepaths from s3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a bunch of files in an s3 bucket with prefixes like the example below.  I would like to connect with boto3 and create a list of all prefixes in the bucket that have a date part older than a day.  So for example if the current date was

```
'20191226_1213'
```

then I would like to create a list like the desired output below.  Can anyone suggest how to do this with boto3?

example:

```
's3://basepath/20191225_1217/'
's3://basepath/20191224_1012/'
's3://basepath/20191222_1114/'
```

desired output:

```
['s3://basepath/20191224_1012/','s3://basepath/20191222_1114/']
```

update:

I'm sorry I didn't provide a better example before but my real folder path actually looks like:

```
's3://basepath/folder1/20191225_1217/'
```

Comment: You can probably do this from the AWS CLI too, if desired. Let me know if that's of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code that extracts the **Common Prefix** in the root of the given bucket and checks their names against "one day ago":

```py
import boto3
import datetime

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

now = datetime.datetime.now()
comparison_time = now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
comparison_time_string = comparison_time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M") # eg 20191225_0623

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket', Delimiter='/')

for prefix_dict in response['CommonPrefixes']:
    prefix = prefix_dict['Prefix']
    if prefix < comparison_time_string}:
        print(prefix)
```

However, be careful about the time definitions. Depending on where you run the code, the timezone might (or might *not*) be set to UTC. This might, or might not, match whatever is generating those dates and times on the folder names.

**Update:** Here's another version that looks for the date string in any part of the Key, then outputs the Key up to the folder name.

```py
import boto3
import datetime
import re

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

now = datetime.datetime.now()
comparison_time = now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
comparison_time_string = comparison_time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M") # eg 20191225_0623

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')

pattern = re.compile('/([\d]{8}_[\d]{4})/') # eg /20191225_0623/

old_objects = []

for object in response['Contents']:
    key = object['Key']
    result = pattern.search(key)
    if result and result.group(1) < comparison_time_string:
        old_objects.append(key[:result.end()])

print(old_objects)
```

Comment: sorry I didn't get back to you sooner, and thank you for the solution.  It would work except I forgot to mention my file paths have extra subdirectories in them.  So when I run your solution it returns all the prefixes filtered by a break before the first '/'.  I've updated my post above with an example.  Do you know how I can solve that issue?

Comment: I've added another sample answer that will find the date in any part of the Key. This is really just manipulation of strings in Python, without much specific to Amazon S3.