# boto3 - Getting files only uploaded in the past month in S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am writing a python3 lambda function which needs to return all of the files that were uploaded to an S3 bucket in the past 30 days from the time that the function is ran.

How should I approach this? Ideally, I want to only iterate through the files from the past 30 days and nothing else - there are thousands upon thousands of files in the S3 bucket that I am iterating through, and maybe 100 max will be updated/uploaded per month. It would be very inefficient to have to iterate through every file and compare dates like that. There is also a 29 second time limit for AWS API gateway.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59146547/9931092

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but one thing I may suggest, is to save your files separated by date in your buckets. When I have buckets with large amounts of files, i tend to save with year/month/day/ prefix. It may help you in the future

Comment: Thanks @RafaelMarques unfortunately, i have no permissions to change the names of any of the files. The buckets are managed by another team that I work with.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to **iterate through the list of objects** (sample code: [List s3 buckets with its size in csv format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61222566/174777)) and compare the date within the Python code (sample code: [Get day old filepaths from s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59495254/174777)).

There is no filter when listing objects (aside from Prefix).

An alternative is to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file listing the contents of a bucket. You could parse that CSV instead of the listing objects.

A more extreme option is to keep a separate database of objects, which would need to be updated whenever objects are added/deleted. This could be done via Amazon S3 Events that trigger an AWS Lambda function. Lots of work, though.

Comment: Each individual upload would result in the Lambda function being called. The `event` record will contain the bucket name and the key of the object that triggered the event.

Comment: sounds great thanks you so much for the quick response! Sorry I deleted my comment, because I wanted to rewrite it, but accidentally deleted it instead of editing it.

Comment: Hi John, so I tried creating the S3 trigger for my lambda, but I get the error: "An error occurred when creating the trigger: Configuration is ambiguously defined. Cannot have overlapping suffixes in two rules if the prefixes are overlapping for the same event type". I think this is because there is already another lambda that gets triggered by an update to S3 (this one gets triggered by the upload of a specific suffix, whereas for me, I need a trigger for all uploads). I am not authorized by my team to touch that other lambda unfortunately. Do you have any advice on this?

Comment: An action in Amazon S3 can only trigger one event. One option would be to have S3 send a message to an SNS topic, which can then trigger multiple Lambda functions. However, that might be difficult if your 'trigger objects' only partially overlap the other team's needs. I suggest either using the Python code or Amazon S3 Inventory.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you an 100% answer, since you have asked for the upload date, but if you can live with the 'last modified' value, this code snippet should do the job:

```
import boto3
import datetime

paginator = boto3.resource('s3').meta.client.get_paginator('list_objects')
date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(30)
filtered_files = (page['Key'] for page in paginator.paginate(Bucket="bucketname").search(f"Contents[?to_string(LastModified)>='\"{date}\"']"))
```

For filterting I used [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/)

Answer (score 0):

### From the architect perspective

The bottle neck is that whether if you can iterate all objects with in 30 seconds. If natively there are too many files, there are a few more options you can use:

1. Create a aws lambda function that triggered by `S3:PutObject` event, and store the S3 key, and last_modified_at information into Dynamodb (A AWS Key Value NoSQL database). Then you can easily use Dynamodb to filter the S3 key and retrieve those S3 object accordingly.
2. Crreate a aws lambda function that triggered by `S3:PutObject` event, and move the file to a partitioned S3 Key schema location such as `s3://bucket/datalake/year=${year}/month=${month}/day=${day}/your-file.csv`. Then you can easily use the partition information to locate the subset of your objects, which fits in 30 seconds hard limit.

### From programming perspective

**Here's the code snippet solves your problem** using this library [s3pathlib](https://s3pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from s3pathlib import S3path

# define a folder
p_dir = S3Path("bucket/my-folder/")

# find one month ago datetime
now = datetime.utcnow()
one_month_ago = now - timedelta(days=30)

# filter by last modified
for p in p_bucket.iter_objects().filter(
    # any Filterable Attribute can be used for filtering
    S3Path.last_modified_at >= one_month_ago 
)：
    # do whatever you like
    print(p.console_url) # click link to open it in console, inspect
```

If you want to use other `S3Path` attributes for filtering, and use other comparators, or even define your custom filter, you can follow this [document](https://s3pathlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/04-S3-Object-Filtering/index.html#)